# Macro with double quotes

Tags: c, macros

I need to create a macro

```
DISP(sqrt, 3.0)
```

that expands into

```
printf("sqrt(%g) = %g\n", 3.0, sqrt(3.0));
```

Here is my current attempt that doesn't quite work yet:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DISP(f,x) printf(#f(%g) = %g\n", x, f(x))

int main(void)
{
  DISP(sqrt, 3.0);
  return 0;
}
```

`gcc -E` shows that I currently have an extra double quote in there.

If I put any double quotes or escaped double quotes before my #f or if I use ##f the macro no longer expands.  How to fix?

Comment: Of course the `"` don't match. There is only one in the code - see answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want this:

```
#define DISP(f,x) printf(#f"(%g) = %g\n", x, f(x))
```

that provides the following output:

`sqrt(3) = 1.73205`

(See http://codepad.org/hX96Leta)

Comment: Good macro discipline is to parenthesize parameters when possible. You can change `f(x)` to `(f)(x)`. This may be unfamiliar syntax for a function designator, but it is proper C and protects in case the macro user passes a more general expression for the `f` argument than just a simple function name.

Comment: And make sure you never pass anything with side effects to this macro, such as `DISP(sqrt, n++);`

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
#define DISP(f,x) printf(#f "(%g) = %g\n", x, f(x))
```

this expands to

```
printf("sqrt" "(%g) = %g\n", 3.0, sqrt(3.0));
```

In C you can combine two or more string literals into one like this:

```
const char *txt = "one" " and" " two";
puts(txt);
```

which will output `one and two`.

**edit**

Also note that it is recommended to put the macro and the macro arguments
inside parenthesis:

```
#define DISP(f,x) (printf(#f "(%g) = %g\n", (x), (f)(x)))
```

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes thanks, I was thinking about the parenthesis when I was writing the answer. I fixed that. Only with `#f` I'm not sure how to use them, if you do `#(f) "(%g)"` then this expands to `("sqrt") "(%g)" and that doesn't work.

Comment: @EricPostpischil right you are, I've removed the unnecessary parenthesis, thanks for the feedback.